# Python ndiff incorrect result

Tags: python

I am trying to compare CSV files with a master CSV file and appending the master file with any changes.  When I run the program I am getting unexpected results.

Python Code:

```
import glob
import difflib

final = "Z:\\_data\\master.csv"
folder = "Z:\\_data\\"

for file in glob.glob( folder + "*sample*.csv"):
    #print file
    diff = difflib.ndiff(open(final).readlines(),open(file).readlines())
    delta1 = ''.join(x[2:] for x in diff if x.startswith('+ '))
    #print delta1

    if delta1 != "":
        with open(final, 'ab') as new_file:
            new_file.write("\n" + delta1)
```

sample1.csv

```
id,tech,type,work_date
C-40,,,
C-33,,,
C-32,,,
```

sample2.csv

```
id,tech,type,work_date
W-37,ty,Waterous,8-12-15
W-38,ty,Dresser,8-12-15
W-5,ty,Waterous,9-1-15
C-44,tf,Waterous,xx
P-40,,,
```

master.csv

```
id,tech,type,work_date
```

When I run the program the first time the master file looks like this:

```
id,tech,type,work_date
id,tech,type,work_date
C-40,,,
C-33,,,
C-32,,,
W-37,ty,Waterous,8-12-15
W-38,ty,Dresser,8-12-15
W-5,ty,Waterous,9-1-15
C-44,tf,Waterous,xx
P-40,,,
```

When I run the program repeatedly I get the following:

```
id,tech,type,work_date
id,tech,type,work_date
C-40,,,
C-33,,,
C-32,,,
W-37,ty,Waterous,8-12-15
W-38,ty,Dresser,8-12-15
W-5,ty,Waterous,9-1-15
C-44,tf,Waterous,xx
P-40,,,
C-32,,,
P-40,,,
```

As you can see the above result has duplicate lines.

I was expecting the result to be

```
id,tech,type,work_date
C-40,,,
C-33,,,
C-32,,,
W-37,ty,Waterous,8-12-15
W-38,ty,Dresser,8-12-15
W-5,ty,Waterous,9-1-15
C-44,tf,Waterous,xx
P-40,,,
```

Comment: And what you expected was...?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be because the last line

```
new_file.write("\n" + delta1)
```

Try remove "\n", just only

```
new_file.write(delta1)
```

I've tried your code on Linux. It generated an extra blank line

```
id,tech,type,work_date

C-40,,,
C-33,,,
C-32,,,

W-37,ty,Waterous,8-12-15
W-38,ty,Dresser,8-12-15
W-5,ty,Waterous,9-1-15
C-44,tf,Waterous,xx
P-40,,,
```

On Windows machine, it might behave differently. Its' probably cause the difference. such as you compare

```
id,tech,type,work_date
```

with
    id,tech,type,work_date\n

On windows you probably don't see the extra blank line since windows use \r\n for the new line.